# how to do json operation in typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to create an json object and add some json objects inside without a key.
I tried to use .push but it returned an error saying .push is not a function. However, it works in Javascript.

my code:

```
var deviceList: any = {};
deviceList.push(jsonObejct);
```

the error is:
`deviceList.push is not a function`

Comment: `var deviceList = {}; deviceList.push(jsonObject);` also doesn't work in Javascript…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push` is used to append the element in the array but here you are declaring an object so basically you can't push the element.

You can do this:

```
var deviceList= new Array();
deviceList.push(jsonObejct);
```

Comment: is it possible to do add element to json in typescript

Comment: You probably mean object because json is not a type, and no, I don't think so